# Protect Iframe From Openining In New Window Or Tab

Tags: iframe, copy-protection

I am adding framed content to a wordpress blog in a membership area. Is there a way that I can prevent that content from being opened in a new window or tab? A plugin or a string of code I can add?

As it is now if someone right clicks on the frames content they can view it in a new window and possibly share that URL rendering the membership site useless in controlling who views....

I would like a block.... If possible...I see other iframes popup an error message when you try and view....

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you for a great place for info

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I can think of is now to add JavaScript code to prevent right click, but again this is not always going to work because the person can simply disable JavaScript and they can still right click to see the content of the iframe. Not only that there is alway a way to sniff the URL of the iframe by either using some sort of software or even using something like FireBug.